# Uninstalling a windows license, can you use it again?

Tags: windows-7, windows, volume-license

I have a windows 7 computer that is licensed with a MAK key from VLS, if I use slmgr /upk will the key seat become available in VLS again?

Comment: Yes, the seat should become available again for use on another computer.

Comment: Also.. in addition to @John comment, if you get an error about licenses and activation, call the windows support number as prescribed.  It's there to keep hackers from stealing windows, not to give legit users a hard time.

Comment: [Be sure you have not exceeded the maximum number of activation on the key.](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/Help/FAQDetails.aspx?id=201#219).  There are incorrect reports that exist that claim Microsoft will expire a key, and all sorts of incorrect reports with regards to license keys, the bottom line is if you key is legitimate 99.9% of the time there is a solution that doesn't require you to purchase another key.  in the case of a MAK key the worst case scenario, you have to increase your activation limit, per your VL agreement.